# Site parsing myip.ms

Tags: python, parsing

Writing a parser for the site https://myip.ms/ And here for this page https://myip.ms/browse/sites/1/ipID/23.227.38.0/ipIDii/23.227.38.255/own/376714 Everything works fine with this link, but if you go to another page https://myip.ms/browse/sites/2/ipID/23.227.38.0/ipIDii/23.227.38.255/own/376714 It does not output any data, although the site structure is the same. I think that this may be due to the fact that the site has a limit on views, or because you need to register, but I can't find what request you need to send to log in to your account. Tell me what to do?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
link_list = []

URL = 'https://myip.ms/browse/sites/2/ipID/23.227.38.0/ipIDii/23.227.38.255/own/376714'

HEADERS = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 YaBrowser/20.12.2.105 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36','accept':'*/*'}
#HOST =
def get_html(url,params=None):
    r = requests.get(url,headers=HEADERS,params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('td',class_='row_name')
    for item in items:
        links = item.find('a').get('href')
        link_list.append({
            'link': links
        })

def parser():
    print(URL)

    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')

parser()
print(link_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SessionID with your request. It will allow you at least 50 requests per day.
If you use proxy that support cookies this number might be even higher.
So the process is as follows:

1. load the page with your browser.
2. find session id in the request inside your Dev Tools.
3. use this session id in your request, no headers or additional info is required.
4. enjoy results for 50 requests per day.
5. repeat in 24 hours.